# GitLab IDE, advice needed

Tags: gitlab, git-branch

I need some advice about using the GitLab IDE. I think I understand what it's done to me, but I don't know how to recover.

I've been making extensive edits to a merge request in the IDE, in the course of which I've pushed several sets of changes. I assumed my changes were going to the branch I created the merge request from -- where else *could* they go? -- but eventually I pulled the repo's updates to my workstation and got "No changes." It turned out that each time I did a Commit & Push from the IDE, it created a new branch by tacking "-patch-" and a four-digit number onto the previous branch's name. The latest branch's name is about 100 characters long.

I think I now understand how to make Commit & Push commit to the current branch instead of creating a new one, although it's very unintuitive, and I won't be sure until I try it. First I need to reunite my changes with my original branch.

How do I do that? The only safe way I know is to pull changes to my local system, then copy the whole contents of the latest branch out of the repo, check out the original branch and copy them back, then commit and push. But I can't do that because, when I pull, none of the branches that the IDE has created are there! On the server, GitLab assures me that they're in the repo; on my workstation, Git insists that they don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

When on your local repository, you can checkout list all remote branches (the ones you see on the website) using `git branch -a` (might need to do a `git fetch -a` before).
Then, you can checkout that branch with `git checkout origin mybranch123` (replace mybranch123 with your branch name).
Then, you can either merge the branch locally, by checking out the target branch (say, `git checkout master`) and then merging the branch (`git merge mybranch123`).
Then, when you push the master branch to remote, it will have the changes merged.

Another option is to create a merge request from the branch with the latest changes within the web UI, which is probably easier.

Here's some more resources:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging
- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-pull-remote-branch-how-to-fetch-remote-branches-in-git/

Hope that answers your question :)